# Why do `1 << 32` and `int i=32; 1 << i` show different result? Is it a bug or feature?

Tags: c++

The code is shown as follow. I tested it on VS, clang++ and G++. All of them show that `1 << 32` and `1 << i`(where i is 32) is different. I took a look at the assemble. It looks like the compiler compute the result of `1 << 32` in compiling. I think this inconsistency should be a bug or it is just another undefined behavior of C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << (1 << 32) << std::endl;
    int i = 32;
    std::cout << (1 << i) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
clang++:
1 << 32:73832
1 << i:1
g++:
1 << 32:73832
1 << i:1
```

Comment: You're saying it gives different results, but aren't showing these results

Comment: Check [the warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/277b5da2e9464284).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I got the warning. I just want to know why `(1<<i)` is different from `(1 << 32)`. I think they should be same.

Comment: So which results did you get?

Comment: @ForceBru I add the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ standard says

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an `unsigned` type, the value of the result is `E1×2^E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if `E1` has a `signed` type and non-negative value, and `E1×2^E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

and then

> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand**.

In this case you shouldn't expect any good.

Answer (score 8):

> std::cout << (1 << 32) << std::endl;

This is [undefined behavior](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c?qid=a1e4ecc1-8319-4915-80eb-64a3ef2b3d2d&v=&b=&from_search=1) if `int` is 4 bytes on your system. From the standard (section about shift operators):

> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. The
>   behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, **or greater
>   than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.**

Answer (score 2):

Both operands to `<<` are `int`s, and thus result is `int`. If `int` is maximum 32 bits wide, a signed integer overflow happens in both cases; signed integer overflow always has had undefined behaviour in both C and C++.

However, many people mistakenly believe that the undefined behaviour means that the *result* is some "unspecified `int`" or that *on their platform the result is `1 << 32 (mod 2³²)`*; however the truth is that on 64-bit platforms compilers tend to use 64-bit registers for 32-bit calculations, knowing that the calculation never can overflow in a conforming program, so in case of undefined behaviour the actual result can also be a value that does not even fit in a 32-bit variable!